# Postfix: How to log to syslog only?

Tags: postfix, logging, journald

I have Postfix 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 23.10. How do I configure Postfix to log to syslog only? My syslog daemon is journald.

According to my understand, Postfix should log to syslog, if `maillog_file` is not set. `postconf` returns

```
root@h12345678:~ # postconf | egrep maillog_file
maillog_file =
maillog_file_compressor = gzip
maillog_file_prefixes = /var, /dev/stdout
maillog_file_rotate_suffix = %Y%m%d-%H%M%S
```

Nonetheless, Postfix writes it logs to `/var/log/mail.log`. Also, `journalctl -eu postfix.service` only returns start/stop messages for the service, but nothing else.

Comment: Quite frequently the default syslog configuration filters out mail message and (also) sends them to /var/log/mail.log

Comment: But this would be a configuration option of `journald`, right? I have already run a `egrep --recursive --include='*' -e 'mail\.log' /etc` to check if there is any configuration file which refers to this log file, but I did not find anything.

Comment: My Ubuntu 22 has  for example `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`. with a default entry `mail.*    -/var/log/mail.log` but your config might be different

Comment: Check who holds it open: `lsof /var/log/mail.log`. On my Debian system that's `rsyslogd`.

Comment: Indeed it was rsyslod. I uninstalled the package and also disabled "forward_to_syslog" in journald.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This answer only repeats the answers provided in the comments so the question doesn't remain unanswered.</sub>

You're correct: when there is no [`maillog_file`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#maillog_file)  set Postfix will log to syslog:

> **`maillog_file` (default: empty)**
>
> The name of an optional logfile that is written by the Postfix postlogd(8) service. An ***empty value selects logging to syslogd***(8). Specify "/dev/stdout" to select logging to standard output. Stdout logging requires that Postfix is started with "postfix start-fg".
>
> Note 1: The maillog_file parameter value must contain a prefix that is specified with the maillog_file_prefixes parameter.
>
> Note 2: Some Postfix non-daemon programs may still log information to syslogd(8), before they have processed their configuration parameters and command-line options.
>
> This feature is available in Postfix 3.4 and later.

Also see: https://www.postfix.org/MAILLOG_README.html

---

The confusion that even when Postfix itself doesn't write to a log file you (still) see log events being written to `/var/log/mail.log` stems from the fact that Postfix uses the syslog  `mail.*` facilities and :

By default rsyslogd on Ubuntu writes out `mail.*` syslog events to `/var/log/maillog`.